# Firefox steals focus of the edge of screen

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

I am using Windows XP and when Firefox is the active window, programs like Objecktdock and Rocketdock, which are activated when the mouse touches the top or the bottom edge of the screen, do not work. Firefox somehow blocks the edge of the screen and docks are not appearing.

I have reported this bug on Firefox support but it still not fixed and I don’t know if they will fix it.

Anyone have any idea if this can be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide the Bugzilla link?

Comment: I sent feedback couple of times.

Comment: That's different from submitting a real bug report. Bug reports are what the actual Firefox developers look at/work on. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/